# Issue with Image picker in swiftui for ios 16

Tags: swiftui, imagepicker, ios16

Good day,

I am new to ios development and trying to make an image picker to print out the path of the images to eventually store in a json file but I keep getting this error

Cannot convert value of type 'Binding' to expected argument type 'Binding'

Here is the code that I am busy with.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
        let parent: ImagePicker

        init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            if let images = info[.originalImage] as? [UIImage] {
                for image in images {
                    print(image)
                }
            }

            parent.$presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    @Binding var presentationMode: PresentationMode
    @Binding var images: [UIImage]

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        picker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        picker.mediaTypes = ["public.image"]
        picker.videoQuality = .typeHigh
        picker.videoMaximumDuration = TimeInterval(30)
        picker.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        return picker
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {
        uiViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 0, height: 0))
    }
}

struct ImagePickerView: View {
    @State private var showImagePicker = false
    @State private var images = [UIImage]()

    var body: some View {
        Button("Select Images") {
            self.showImagePicker = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showImagePicker, onDismiss: {
            self.showImagePicker = false
        }, content: {
            ImagePicker(presentationMode: self.$showImagePicker, images: self.$images)
        })
    }
}

struct ImagePickerViewPreviews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ImagePickerView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues:

1. You're trying to pass a `Binding<Bool>` to a `Binding<PresentationMode>`
2. You are trying to convert to a `[UIImage]` instead of `UIImage`

You actually don't need the `PresentationMode` at all -- you can just use the single `Bool` binding for `showImagePicker` since all you're doing is trying to effect whether the view is shown or not.

See comments for the changed lines:

```
struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
        let parent: ImagePicker

        init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            // <-- Here
            if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                self.parent.images = [image]
            }

            parent.showImagePicker = false // <-- Here
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    @Binding var showImagePicker: Bool // <-- Here
    @Binding var images: [UIImage]

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        picker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        picker.mediaTypes = ["public.image"]
        picker.videoQuality = .typeHigh
        picker.videoMaximumDuration = TimeInterval(30)
        picker.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        return picker
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {
        uiViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 0, height: 0))
    }
}

struct ImagePickerView: View {
    @State private var showImagePicker = false
    @State private var images = [UIImage]()

    var body: some View {
        Button("Select Images") {
            self.showImagePicker = true
        }
        // <-- Here
        .sheet(isPresented: $showImagePicker) {
            ImagePicker(showImagePicker: $showImagePicker, images: $images)
        }
        .onChange(of: images) { newValue in
            print("Images: ", newValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it sort of works it only allows me to choose one image and it outputs this   Images:  [<UIImage:0x600000eecea0 anonymous {4288, 2848} renderingMode=automatic(original)>] Instead of a path to the actually image or am I supposed to be doing it another way because what I am try to do is get the path to the images and then store it in a json file to retrieve to use to show the images in another view.

Comment: I addressed the question you had. Now it sounds like you’re expanding the scope of it.